# Google Map API - How to Stop Scrolling (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scroll

I am trying to stop scrolling on my Google Map. I've looked at other questions and most answers have said to put scrollwheel: false into your map options, however this has not worked. Does anyone have any pointers for this?

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.843143, -2.643555),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: myLatlng
    }),
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<b>Paddle the Wye base</b>"
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "We are here!"
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

  var accessPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.840913, -2.638603),
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: accessPoint1,
      map: map,
      title: "Access Point 1"
    });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($("#findButton")[0]);


  function successCallback(position) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude),

      myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      },
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latlng);

    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

    map.setOptions(myOptions);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      title: "You are here!",
      icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png'
    });
  }

  function errorCallback() {
    alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
  }

  function findMe() {
    $(this).hide();

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
        timeout: 10000
      });
    } else {
      alert("I'm afraid your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }
  }

  $("#findButton").click(findMe);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand your code completely, but you have to add it here:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.843143, -2.643555),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: myLatlng,
-->      scrollwheel: false
    }),
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it a bit in the question. Thanks for your help, I feel like a fool now!

Comment: @FranHaines Don't say that, everybody make mistakes!